# Kafka Stopped after some time

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka

I have Kafka runnning for many days. After few days kafka stops working with below exception

> ERROR Exception emitting metrics
>   (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.kafka.KafkaTimelineMetricsReporter)
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.timeline.UnableToConnectException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.timeline.AbstractTimelineMetricsSink.emitMetrics(AbstractTimelineMetricsSink.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.kafka.KafkaTimelineMetricsReporter.access$200(KafkaTimelineMetricsReporter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.kafka.KafkaTimelineMetricsReporter$TimelineScheduledReporter.report(KafkaTimelineMetricsReporter.java:253)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.kafka.ScheduledReporter.report(ScheduledReporter.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.kafka.ScheduledReporter$1.run(ScheduledReporter.java:137)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)    at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.timeline.AbstractTimelineMetricsSink.emitMetrics(AbstractTimelineMetricsSink.java:78)

Inorder to kafka accept messages sent to it , I have to restart kafka when such thing happens.
Can anybody help me as to why the above exception occurs? Is there any configuration change required to get it working all the time?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Even I faced same issue. Kafka server stops just after couple of hours.